# Order by on Two column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table as per below.

[image]

I need the result as per below image.

[image]

I need record order by ID with the dependencyFK column.
For example first row ID=1 so the second record come with 1 dependencyFk then again check ID value and then dependency value.

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Comment: You have... you need, i'm missing your effort

Comment: yes, the question is not clear enough. what are you trying to achieve? why do you need this solution? it doesn't seem to be the result of an order by.

Comment: What is the logic in words? Can you write an explanation in plain english, then we can help you with the sql.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain a *hierarchical* sort? So that every "child" of a particular parent appears after it and before any *siblings* of the parent?

Comment: Take a step back: Do you really need to do this in your db query? From the column names it sounds like you are dealing with UI elements and usually presentation frameworks have methods to handle hierarchical control trees.

Answer (score 2):

You can build up a representation of the full hierarchy using a recursive CTE, and then use the built in [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference) type which knows how to sort hierarchies correctly:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, controlName varchar(17) not null, dependencyFK int null)
insert into @t(ID,controlName,dependencyFK) values
(1 ,'One'   ,null),
(2 ,'Two'   ,1),
(3 ,'Three' ,2),
(4 ,'Four'  ,2),
(5 ,'Five'  ,null),
(6 ,'Six'   ,1),
(7 ,'Seven' ,5),
(8 ,'Eight' ,null),
(9 ,'Nine'  ,5),
(10,'Ten'   ,null)

;With BuiltHierarchy as (
    select *,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),ID) + '/' as Hier
    from @t
    union all
    select bh.ID, bh.controlName, o.dependencyFK,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),o.ID) + Hier as Hier
    from BuiltHierarchy bh
    inner join
    @t o on bh.dependencyFK = o.ID
)
select *
from BuiltHierarchy
where dependencyFK is null
order by CONVERT(hierarchyid,Hier)
```

At the same time, you may wish to consider switching to actually using this type directly in modelling your hierarchy rather than using your existing "child points at parent" representation, which is less amenable to performing general processing of hierarchical data.

Result:

```
ID          controlName       dependencyFK Hier
----------- ----------------- ------------ -----
1           One               NULL         /1/
2           Two               NULL         /1/2/
3           Three             NULL         /1/2/3/
4           Four              NULL         /1/2/4/
6           Six               NULL         /1/6/
5           Five              NULL         /5/
7           Seven             NULL         /5/7/
9           Nine              NULL         /5/9/
8           Eight             NULL         /8/
10          Ten               NULL         /10/
```